# Is it possible to make a block like tall grass solid, so that players are unable to pass through?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My friend and I are adding this new game to our server, and the map is this huge maze of reeds.

I'm trying to make it so you can't go through the reeds. I was wondering if I could make a block like tall grass 'solid' with commands, or whether I should re-texture a solid block to *look* like tall grass instead.

I looked it up, and I can't find anything about it online. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score -2):

You could summon invisible noai slimes in the blocks, could cause lag though.

Comment: Could you possibly give the user more help with this - such as an example of what sort of command to use as unless they have lots of experience using commands themselves this answer is unlikely to be very helpful to them

Comment: I might be able to do that. Maybe..